# How to set up git so that I can see the content in repository

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a git repository on a server. I read few articles that I am supposed to have a bare repository on the server and have local machine with non bare repository. But when I try to push to that remote repository (bare) I am not able to.

I believe that I am understanding the purpose of bare repository wrong, which is causing me to face this problem. What can I do to have the repository on the server to work as a storage for files along with managing files version control? (I would like the remote server to also contain those files, and not be synced to github)

One way I tried to overcome this was by having another non bare repository on the server created using `git clone` but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: What did you use? In what way did it not work? (What error message did you get?)

Comment: @ikegami I just created readme file on my local repo and `git push` after committing. `The error message that I get is fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream README.md master` and I tried with --set-upstream flag. I got invalid gitfile format as an error

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
git push
```

with no additional arguments, Git needs to know *what to send* and *where to send it*.

The *where to send it* part is normally the name of a *remote*.  The usual name for the (single) remote is `origin`, so:

```
git push origin
```

tells Git where to send it: to `origin`.  Git still needs to know *what to send*.

When you use `git push`, you select some commit or commits to send.  The defaults here depend on your Git version, but you probably have Git 2.0 or later (an earlier one with its default would give you a different error, or no error).  In this case, the default is to look for information associated with your *current branch name*.

(The error message, which you should have put into the question itself, not as a comment added later, says that you are on `master`.)

The information Git is looking for is called the *upstream*.  Every branch name like `master` can have one upstream set.  To set the upstream, you can use:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<target>
```

The `target` here will specify *both* the *remote* (`origin`) *and* the *branch name on the remote*, which in this case would be `master`.  Your Git will then ask their Git—the one on `origin`—to set *their* master, based on the commit(s) your Git sends as found by *your* `master`.

The error message you quoted:

> ```
> use git push --set-upstream README.md master
> ```

is not something Git would print; it would say instead:

```
use git push --set-upstream origin master
```

This `--set-upstream` flag is a convenience flag.  You don't *have* to do it, just as you don't *have* to use `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  You *can* just run:

```
git push origin master
```

every time, to tell your Git: *call up the Git at `origin`; give him commits from my `master`, and ask him to set his `master`*.

If you run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

you will set the upstream for the *current branch* to `origin/master`, which means you can now run `git push` with no arguments.  Or, if you run:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

(note the different spelling of each argument!) your Git will perform the initial `git push origin master` the same way you would have, but then if that succeeds, your Git will run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

Note that this is slightly different from before: this tells your Git to set the upstream of your `master` to `origin/master`, rather than setting the upstream of your *current branch*.  Since your current branch *is* `master`, it all works out to the same thing.